# New custom modern search verticals not showing up

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, verticals

I've added two new custom search verticals for a SharePoint Online site using the option "Configure Search settings > Verticals".

But they are not showing up in the search results page, it only shows the default verticals (All, Files, Sites, News, Images) which I have disabled the Images.
It has been couple of days now.

Any tips here and has anyone experienced the same?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone from MS here? My custome search verticals still aren't showing up